# Trying to deploy to azure- changes won't take place

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to deploy the bot to Azure using VS Studio, it says that the deployment was successful but the changes won't take place.
I've tried deploying from 2 different computers and still not working.

Did anyone encountered such an issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked in the Deployment Center section of the web app that is associated with the bot in Azure? There is a guide in how to get to the deployment center [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment#authorize-azure-app-service) . If the deployment actually succeeded then you should see some entries.

Comment: Are you still working on this? (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)